# Не работают методы сущности в JSP файле

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Открываю сессию и получаю коллекцию объектов, затем передаю ее в JSP-файл:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
List<Match> matches = session.createQuery("from Match").list();
servletRequest.setAttribute("matches", matches);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

JSP - файл принимает коллекцию, и я с помощью JSTL пытаюсь вытащить данные из каждого объекта коллекции но бросается исключение.

```
<c:forEach var="match" items="${matches}">
  <tr>
    <td>${match.getPlayerOne()}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Если оставить только переменную `match` без методов, то все работает. Но мне необходимо же только имя, а не наименование объекта.
Не могу понять что не так.

Answer (score 0):

Методы сущности в `JSP` файле могут не работать по разным причинам. Вот некоторые возможные решения:

1. Убедитесь, что вы импортировали правильный пакет для сущности. Например, если вы используете `JPA`, то вы должны импортировать пакет `javax.persistence.Entity`.
2. Убедитесь, что вы правильно настроили связь между вашей базой данных и вашим приложением.
3. Проверьте, что у вас есть правильные зависимости в вашем файле `pom.xml` (если вы используете `Maven`) или `build.gradle` (если вы используете `Gradle`).
4. Убедитесь, что у вас есть правильно настроенный контейнер сервлетов, который поддерживает `JSP`.
5. Проверьте, что вы используете правильный синтаксис для вызова методов сущности. Например, вы должны использовать `${entity.fieldName}` для доступа к полям сущности.
6. Если вы используете `JPA`, то убедитесь, что ваша сущность правильно настроена с аннотациями, такими как `@Id`, `@Column` и т.д.
7. Проверьте, что ваше приложение правильно скомпилировано и развернуто на сервере.

Если вы продолжаете испытывать проблемы, можете предоставить дополнительную информацию о вашем коде и окружении, чтобы мы могли дать более конкретные рекомендации.